# How to refresh vscode.treeview items to show status when performing long running task

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

I am writing a simple extension for vscode (npm task Runner). I am using custom view with treeview. It shows npm tasks found in project.

Each TreeItem in view has registered command "run" to perform this task. When  handling "run" command I want to update tree view item multiple times. At start - to set an running icon and after execution to set "finished" or "error" icon.

I am using custom TreeDataProvider. It provides items for treeview. It also listens to icon change of its item and when this occures it fires `onDidChangeTreeData`. This listener works correctly. It first sets icon to running, fires `onDidChangeTreeData` then the task is running few seconds and after that it sets "finished" icon and again fires `onDidChangeTreeData`. The problem is that the UI updates only once after everithing is done. "Running" icon is never shown, instead it shows default icon for few seconds and after command execution is done it sets "fishihed" icon.

```
export class TaskDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<Task> {

    private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<any> = new vscode.EventEmitter<any>();
    readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<any> = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

    public refresh(): any {
        this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
    }
}
```

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const taskManager = new TaskManager();
    const taskDataProvider = new TaskDataProvider(taskManager);

    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.run', (item: Task) => {
       item.setIcon(TaskStatus.Running);
       taskDataProvider.refresh();
       item.execute() //async task 
         .then( () => {
             item.setIcon(TaskStatus.finished);
             taskDataProvider.refresh();
       });
    }
```

It seems treeview is updating only once per command. It fires `onDidChangeTreeData` when it is supposed to but no updates are really peformend. The update occurs only once after everything has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using `setTimeout`. It works but it is not as clean approach as I would like.

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.run', (item: Task) => {
       item.setIcon(TaskStatus.Running);
       taskDataProvider.refresh();
       setTimeout(()=> 
           item.execute() //async task 
             .then( () => {
                 item.setIcon(TaskStatus.finished);
                 taskDataProvider.refresh();
           }), 1);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).